# if exist not working in batch

Tags: batch-file, operating-system

I am trying to make a .bat file that creates a simple text file. My problem is Windows XP home folder is `C:\Documents and Settings` while vista and above its `C:\Users\`

I am running this and no matter what I put for the path name, I always get `it exists`

```
@echo off
if exist C:\Documents and Settings\ (
    echo it exists
    Pause
) else (
    echo file not found
    Pause
)
```

When I run the above I get `it exists` when in fact it does not since I am windows 7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Um, that directory exists in Windows 7. It's just hidden. Type "dir /a c:\" to see it.

Comment: Its saying its a junction..whats that? and if I do c:\Documents in Settings in explorer it says folder not found

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851567.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing quotes around the path.  Second `EXIST` only checks if files exist.  There are a few secret files Windows uses in its file system.  Try the following:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Documents and Settings\NUL" (
    echo it exists
    Pause
) else (
    echo Folder not found
    Pause
)
```

Comment: +1 Complete answer. NUL is not a "secret file", it's just a way to check if folder exists. The folder may be empty.