# DOS batch file required for drive and if

Tags: batch-file, dos

Can anyone help me with a batch file?

I have a mapped drive Z:, and this is my batch file:

```
z:
cd Z:\KiwiTEMP\
ERASE /S /Q log12*.log
```

My problem is, if the map drive is not available due to some reason, the `ERASE` command is executed on the c: drive, which deletes my required log files.

I'm trying to figure out:

If Z: exists:

```
cd Z:\KiwiTEMP\ 
ERASE /S /Q log12*.log
else exit or terminate
```

Comment: See if this solution works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888230/if-exist-not-working-in-batch

Answer (score 0):

With this command it  should not go to c: drive, if you have same folder in c: drive as well, try to rename the name of that folder

z:

cd Z:\KiwiTEMP\

ERASE /S /Q log12*.log